# How to make Cycle2's first child not be a slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a web-page utilizing the cycle2's Jquery plugin. The problem I am having is that I want to have certain elements (arrows, paragraphs) on the slider. I don't want to 'absolute position' my elements, because I want to let them be dictated by the flow of the page, but for some reason, I am unable to place the elements before the actual slides.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow slide-container" data-cycle-fx="fade" data-cycle-slides="> div.slide"
     style="position: relative;">

    <div class="triangle">
        <p>Test123</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
            <h2>Test123</h2>
    </div>

   <div class="slide">
            <h2>Test123</h2>
    </div>
```

Problem is that whenever I open my page, the very first child is put in front of my .triangle div, and thus all the elements I would like to put before the slides are hidden in between the slides instead.

Is there a way to make the first element or stick, or else, am I overseeing some simple CSS trick where I can position my 'relative' item over my slider?

This is what my dom returns(the smaller triangle is not related to the triangle element, part of the image):

[triangle under slide http://puu.sh/nqZze/904347f770.jpg](http://puu.sh/nqZze/904347f770.jpg)

This is what happens when I drag the second element from the dom to the 'first position:

[triangle first child http://puu.sh/nqZHF/0cc168af03.jpg](http://puu.sh/nqZHF/0cc168af03.jpg)

The second image is the effect I want, without using position absolute.

Comment: Any chance we can see your website or example an action?

Comment: I added two images to explain what I meant, hopefully that adds a bit more clarification?